# How to bring dialogbox on top all open form

Tags: c#

I have three forms Main, Sales and Login.

In Main form I have a timer, example after 5 minutes Login form will be fire up.

I can Open a Sales form the Main form whitout closing the Main form, so Login form will be fire up.

The problem is the Login form does not focus on top of the Sales form, so that the user must login to use the sales form.

Some code on Main form :

```
public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
    LoginDialog loginForm = new LoginDialog();
                loginForm.TopLevel = true;
                loginForm.ShowDialog();
timer.Start()
}

 private void pbSales_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sales salesForm = new Sales();
            salesForm .ShowDialog(this);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is you are calling `ShowDialog` from the `MainForm` and you have the Sales Form open also.

The parent for the Dialog happens to be the `MainForm`, so maybe you can try using

`loginForm.ShowDialog(saleform1);`

salesform1 is the instance name of the Sales Form you opened from the Main form.

Comment: Yes That is what I ask. I have tried the method before posting  loginForm.ShowDialog(new Sales()); Sales is the form.

Comment: and how do you `Show()` the sales form ?

Comment: from the main form Sales salesForm = new Sales(); salesForm .ShowDialog(this); Please refer the code edited above.

Comment: Ok, so did you try in the timer `ShowDialog(salesForm)` as salesForm is the form instance which is shown/open and then the login would be placed on top of it

Comment: Tried, it works, but now how do I know which form I am opening, because main form can fire the login form too.

Comment: Well you can use `salesForm ?? this`, so that should take care of case when salesForm is null/not opened.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

try combination of both that will might work for you..

```
private void frmMain_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Make this form the active form and make it TopMost
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.TopMost = true;
this.Focus();
this.BringToFront();
this.TopMost = false;
}
```

---

try this out

```
yourForm.TopMost = true;
```

or

[Control.BringToFront Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx)

```
yourform.BringToFront()
```

Comment: I tried both. Top Most is on top of all program I am opening.

Comment: TopMost is great if it is not on top of all other program I am opening, like browser.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried not working, I have change the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle around with `TopMost` and `BringToFront()`